# Enabling scroll bar on y-axis of the high charts heatmap showing up some additional y-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to generate heat map for the large set of series data with same x and y-axis categories and scrollbars enabled for both x & y-axis. Problem is y-axis is showing up some additional labels with an empty plot area which did not get solved by setting endOnTicket to false

Here is the graph with sample data, Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/graji/mdu37kq8/9/

```
yAxis: {
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  categories: ['abc', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4', 'abc5', 'abc6', 'abc7', 'abc8', 'abc9', 'abc10', 'abc11', 'abc12', 'abc13', 'abc14', 'abc15', 'abc16', 'abc17', 'abc18', 'abc19', 'abc20', 'abc21', 'abc22', 'abc23', 'abc24', 'abc25', 'abc26', 'abc27', 'abc28', 'abc29', 'abc30', 'abc31', 'abc32', 'abc33', 'abc34', 'abc35', 'abc36', 'abc37', 'abc38', 'abc39'],
  title: null,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than 1000 points which causes the third value to be treated as Y value. You need to disable **turboThreshold** property:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    turboThreshold: 0
  }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f2kqgson/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.turboThreshold